# How to declare arraylist to store integers and strings in android?

Tags: android

I am new to arraylist concept. Please help me how to declare arraylist and add strings and integers to it.

```
String str = quesid+","+k1;
                             ArrayList<Object> arl=new ArrayList<Object>();
                             arl.add("str");
```

In the above code the string didnt added to arraylist. Where I went wrong...plz help me

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Do you really want to store String and Integer in the same array? As this is not a good java practice...

Answer (score 6):

Make a `custom class`, and put String and Int member fields now also make a getter() setter() methods for that fields in that class,
Now use that class in your ArrayList, Simple :-)

EDIT: Example

```
List<CustomClass> foo = ArrayList<CustomClass>


public class CustomClass
{
  private String result;
  private int count;

  public CustomClass() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
   }
   public void setResult(String res)
   {
     this.result=res;
   }
   public void setCount(int cnt)
   {
    this.count=cnt;
   }

   public String getResult()
   {
    return this.result;
   }
   public int getCount()
   {
    return this.count;
   }

}
```

In your activity,

```
 List<CustomClass> foo = ArrayList<CustomClass>
      CustomClass cust = new CustomClass();
      cust.setResult("Test");
      cust.setCount(1);

      foo.add(cust);
```

To retrieve data...

```
 String res = foo.get(0).getResult();
 int count = foo.get(0).getCount();
```

You can directly **set a values by passing it to CustomClass constructor**.. (In this case you have to modify constructor of CustomClass) Choice is yours.

Answer (score 3):

Define a class as such:

```
public class StringInt{

private String s;
private int i;

public StringInt(String o1, int o2){
s = o1;
i = o2;
}

public String getString(){
return s;
}

public int getInt(){
return i;
}

public void setString(String s){
this.s = s;
}

public void setInt(int i){
this.i = i;
}

}
```

Then use is in an ArrayList

```
ArrayList<StringInt> arl = new ArrayList<StringInt>();
arl.add(new StringInt("Test", 15));
```

Edit: user370305 had the same idea. Great minds think alike? :P